# MEAN app crashing Safari

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I wish that I could be more specific in this question, but I don't have much information to go off of. I'm working on a MEAN app that has to populate a lengthy form's default values with values pulled from the database, using ng-bind. This works fine, most of the time. However, in Safari, approximately 20% of the time, navigating between two pages that each have one of these forms...especially when switching back and forth rapidly... the app locks up, I get a lengthy and unhelpful Angular error, and I have to refresh to get things going again. After refresh, everything's back to working. This doesn't occur in Firefox, or in Chrome. My feeling is that angular is faltering when the database info that it's attempting to ng-bind doesn't 'arrive' quickly. But, as is happening in the other browsers, the page should still load, maybe with a few empty {{}}'s, until the database info arrives. Instead, it freaks out.

I know this doesn't give you much to work with, but I'm wondering if others have experienced similar issues with MEAN and Safari? Does anyone have any thoughts as to whether to look more closely at my Mongoose, Express, AngularJS, or Node? Is this Mongoose lagging? Is this an Angular hangup? Is it me?

Here's the (I think, unhelpful) Angular error that's being thrown in Safari, though I suspect that the problem doesn't actually originate with Angular:

```
[Error] Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.nodeType')
append@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:170:200
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:173:98
wa@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:14:333
$@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:70:225
B@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:59:256
g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:51:336
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:50:445
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:52:323
k@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:56:323
x@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js:6:505
$broadcast@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:128:365
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js:11:438
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:112:114
$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:15
$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:123:111
$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:300
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:100:132
c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:32:393
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 102)
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 76)
    $broadcast (angular.min.js, line 128)
    (anonymous function) (angular-route.min.js, line 11)
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 112)
    $eval (angular.min.js, line 126)
    $digest (angular.min.js, line 123)
    $apply (angular.min.js, line 126)
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 100)
    c (angular.min.js, line 32)
```

Any thoughts, ideas for some detective work here welcome.
Thanks